# Python – Scrape URL from one page, then open/parse separately

Tags: python, parsing, screen-scraping

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to write a script that will parse the homepage of a news website, find the first article listed, scrape the URL for that article, then follow that link to parse the article itself.

What I have below currently works to find the first headline, print it, and scrape the URL, but I cannot work out how to open the URL that is printed and then scrape that page.

Can anyone offer any help? I'd really appreciate it! This is frying my brain a bit.

Many thanks in advance, the code I currently have is below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import html
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

source = requests.get('http://www.examplehomepage.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

# Print headline of first article on homepage
headline = soup.find('h2').text
print(headline)

# Extract URL for first article on homepage
lead_article = soup.find('h2')
for link in lead_article.find_all('a'):
    try:
        sys.stdout.write('http://www.examplehomepage.com')
        sys.stdout.write(link['href'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: Just do another requests.get and open the url

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. Do you know if it's possible to automate that process? Currently it prints the URL in the text box at the bottom of the editor, but I'm not sure how to make it open that URL. Sorry, I might need a bit of extra help!

Comment: What do you mean by open? Do you want to use something like webbrowser?